# Why isn't jest's clearAllMocks working and how do I clear mocks for jest spies?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, spy

I'm using jest 4.2.4 with my React 16.13.0 application.  I have set up this type of mock ...

```
  jest.spyOn(ReduxFirebase, "getFirebase").mockReturnValue({
    firestore: jest.fn(() => ({ collection: jest.fn(() => collection) })),
  });
```

How do I clear this between tests?  I tried this ...

```
describe("User", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
```

but it is not working.  Setting this later in the test suite

```
  jest.spyOn(ReduxFirebase, "getFirebase").mockReturnValue({
    firestore: jest.fn(() => ({ collection: jest.fn(() => collection2) })),
  });
```

does not take (the original spy is still in place.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. How do you know that it doesn't work? What do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 6):

This should do the job :

```js
const getFirebaseMock = jest.spyOn(ReduxFirebase, "getFirebase").mockReturnValue({
  firestore: jest.fn(() => ({ collection: jest.fn(() => collection) })),
});
getFirebaseMock.mockRestore();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Currently I'm not savinga  reference to that anywhere.  Is there any way I can start out the test suite (or an individual test) with a clean state without saving any state from anything before?

Comment: I'm not sure you can if `clearAllMocks` does not work. You'll probably need to define your spy before the test suite, mock implementation in each test and use `afterEach(getFirebaseMock.mockRestore)`

Comment: Apart from this case you can't clear your mock to retrieve the originally state. Besides an issue has been opened, check here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7136

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
```